# Change column name in downloaded file from highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts

I would like to change the column names of the .csv file after exporting from highcharter.
For example, the current column names are "flipper_length_mm" and "Penguins" but is it possible to change them to "X" and "Y"?

I think highcharts has an option to change column names but I am not too familiar with JS to change it myself. ([Change Highchart's pie chart .xls file category column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257457/change-highcharts-pie-chart-xls-file-category-column-name))

```
library(highcharter)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")
penguins <- penguins[complete.cases(penguins),]

hchart(
  penguins,
  "scatter",
  name = "Penguins",
  hcaes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = bill_length_mm)) |>
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `hc_xAxis()` and `hc_yAxis`:

```
hchart(
  penguins,
  "scatter",
  name = "Penguins",
  hcaes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = bill_length_mm)) |>
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "x")) |>
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "y")) |>
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that I prefer not changing the names shown on the chart.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please clarify what you want to change  where and when?

Comment: If you click on the menu on the top right hand corner, there is an option to export to csv. I would like to only change the column names in the downloaded file.